# JavaServer Pages: How to get a value into an attribute from code without Expression Language?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, el

I am using the MyFaces 1.1 ValidateRegExpr tag to validate the input from a user against a regular expression.

I would like to be able to dynamically assign the regex pattern via code, but according to http://myfaces.apache.org/commons11/myfaces-validators11/tagdoc/mcv_validateRegExpr.html the attribute pattern does not support Expression Language.

The markup in my JSP file is supposed to look like this:

```
<tc:in value="${dataBean.currentBean.field}">
        <mcv:validateRegExpr
            pattern="${dataBean.currentBean.validationRegEx}"
            message="${dataBean.currentBean.validationMessage" />
</tc:in>
```

What is the preferred way of dynamically assigning attribute values to jsp controls that do not support EL?

Answer (score 1):

Implement a [`javax.faces.validator.Validator`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html) and register it as `<validator>` in `faces-config.xml`. In a real Java class you have the freedom to write normal Java code :)

Basic kickoff example:

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    SomeBean someBean = SomeFacesUtil.evaluateExpressionGet("someBean", SomeBean.class);
    if (!value.toString().matches(someBean.getPattern())) {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(someBean.getMessage()));
    }
}
```